# turbine : request rate of host & cluster only of half of the actual value

Tags: turbine

I use turbine to monitor a cluster of tow instance, the request rate of host & cluster in turbine dashboard just equal to the value in the hystirx dashboard of a single instance. It means that when I sum the value of two instance, the request rate of host & cluster in turbine dashboard is only half of the acture value.
The full context of application.yml in turbine:

```
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
spring:
  application:
    name: turbine
server:
  port: 9386
turbine:
  app-config: xxx
  cluster-name-expression: aSGName
  instanceUrlSuffix:
    xxx: xxx/hystrix.stream
  aggregator:
      cluster-config: xxx

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://eurekahost:9396/eureka/
  instance:
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 30
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 10
    prefer-ip-address: true
```

Any help will be welcome!

above is hystrix, below is turbine

[image]

Comment: Thanks Hitesh, I'm new here~